# Parsing a distance matrix csv into python dictionary structure

Tags: python, csv, parsing, matrix, distance

I have a distance matrix laid out like this in a csv file

```
 , A, B, C,
A, 0
B, 3, 0
C, 6, 4, 0
```

And I would like to parse it into a python dictionary like this...

```
graph = {'A': {'B': 3, 'C': 6},
         'B': {'A': 3, 'C': 4},
         'C': {'A': 6, 'B': 4}}
```

Comment: Check for `pandas.read_csv`

Answer (score 0):

With the file you specified, you will never get that dict in `graph`. In any case, if you provide the correct CSV file, the code below will result in exactly what you want.

Just pay attention that inside the CSV file, you cannot have a comma in the end of the header row (first row), and you cannot have spaces in the column names (first row). Otherwise, you'll get a weird `dict`.

```
import pandas
import io
import math

d = pandas.read_csv('csv_file.csv',sep=',',header=0,index_col=0)
d_dict = d.to_dict() # use d.to_dict(orient='index') for the transpose
graph = { k.strip():{ k2.strip():v2 for k2,v2 in v.items() if not math.isnan(v2) } for k,v in d_dict.items() }

print(graph)
```

which generates the corresponding dict

```
{'A': {'A': 0, 'B': 3, 'C': 6},
 'B': {'B': 0.0, 'C': 4.0},
 'C': {'C': 0.0}}
```

the csv_file.csv

```
 ,A,B,C
 A, 0
 B, 3, 0
 C, 6, 4, 0
```